# What is the best approch to develope design for multiple screens for android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am using screen parent view width to design child view layouts in parent view, is this good idea to develop design in android instead of creating multiple XML for deign?

Any suggestion are accepted.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest asking on a message board.

Comment: Using multiple dimens files is one way, or create multiple XML files and don't use hardcoded size in the XML file like `layout_width="50dp"`[ResponsiveUI](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/flexible-and-responsive-ui-b17a895b2d52?source=your_stories_page-------------------------------------)